# XSS Filtering won't disable on post codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, xss

I'm in the process of developing a basic WYSIWYG for my site and I've used this line to turn XSS filtering off

```
$this->input->post(NULL, FALSE);
```

I have also tried

```
$this->input->post();
```

as I understand it, this should give me all postdata and not filter it, however, it appears to still be removing my `<script>` tags. Disregarding security concerns for now (I'll handle those still) how can I guarantee that my scripts are not removed without disabling XSS for my entire site?

P.S. I have also verified that `$config['global_xss_filtering']` is set to false.

Comment: Have you checked your config files?  You can have it globally enabled there.

Comment: $config['global_xss_filtering'] = false;

Comment: Just a note, Codeigniter doesn't remove all tags, it removes some tags that you usually won't use for a WYSIWYG editor(I assume). Here's the list of "naughty" HTML words that will get encoded by Codeigniter: `"alert|applet|audio|basefont|base|behavior|bgsound|blink|body|embed|expression|form|frameset|frame|head|html|ilayer|iframe|input|isindex|layer|link|meta|object|plaintext|style|script|textarea|title|video|xml|xss"`You should disable XSS filtering only if you're using anything in the "naughty" list, otherwise I don't see any reason of disabling it.

Comment: @AzizAG as for disabling XSS filtering, a better solution it so remove any tag that you'll use from the naughty list(be **careful**) The list could be found in `system/core/Security.php line 427`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the CI documentation, if you're looking to pull the whole post array without XSS, you should replace `$this->input->post(NULL, FALSE);`  with `$this->input->post();`

See http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html

Comment: This would be all well and good (because Null, false are the defaults for that function) except it's still filtering.

Comment: Got me stumped for now.  Have you tried debugging this as a solitary item? ie. post to a method who's only code is `print_r( $this->input->post() );` or something like that?  If you want to post more code, I'll check it out, but I've looked into the CI core and you seem to be fine with what you have above.

Comment: Turns out it was something in a custom controller we had in our system that was overriding that setting. Thanks for the help though :D

Comment: This is incorrect. When xss is set to TRUE in the config file, filtering is done BEFORE the controllers are loaded. So Setting the `$this->input->post()` to anything wont make a difference at all.